# BugSnag ErrorBoundary not showing custom error page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bugsnag

I am working on a SPA using React.

Currently, in production, user only sees a blank page when the app crashes.

So, I am trying to set a custom error page.

Since I am using BugSnag for error monitoring in my react app; I have used the ErrorBoundary provided by BugSnag.

Following is the code for initializing and placing the ErrorBoundary.

```
const bugsnagClient = bugsnag('8XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXbac')
bugsnagClient.use(bugsnagReact, React)
const ErrorBoundary = bugsnagClient.getPlugin('react')

ReactDOM.render(
<ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={FallBack}>
    <IntlProvider locale={language} messages={messages[language]}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </IntlProvider>
</ErrorBoundary>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Following is the custom error code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fallbackVector from '../assets/500-error-vector.svg';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class FallBack extends Component{

    render(){

        return(
            <div className="container-fluid mt-3 mb-3 mt-md-5 mb-md-5">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 col--404 text-center">
                        <img src={fallbackVector} alt="page not found" />
                        <p className="mt-5 font-weight-bold">Something went wrong!</p>
                        <Link to="/">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary mt-3">GO TO HOME</button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Somehow, it is still showing the blank page.

There can be a possibility that error is happening outside of the React component tree and therefore it is not being caught by ErrorBoundry.

Any ideas about how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If the error happens outside of the React component tree then it wouldn't be caught by the ErrorBoundary and the Fallback component won't be rendered.

If you have a reproduction case which triggers an error in the React component tree where this isn't working then please contact us at Bugsnag Support and we'll take a look.

Comment: I am not sure what outside of the React Component tree means but following code in render() method is causing the error: `<img style={{height:'50px',background:'#fff',borderRadius:'8px'}} src={this.props.voucher.image_url} alt={this.props.voucher.name} />`

Comment: I can see the following error in console: bugsnag.js:2180 TypeError: Cannot read property 'image_url' of null